# How to install wso2 BAM

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I downloaded zip file in wso2 and i extracted the file as /home/Downloads/jacksphere/LatestVersion/wso2bam-2.3.0/bin and run at server side,but it is not showing some errors,is there any pre requisites to install the product any one help us and explain the procedure how to run the bam server..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only pre-requisite required for running WSO2 BAM is JDK1.6 or higher. For further information please checkout the documentation [WSO2 BAM Documentation](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM230/Installation+Prerequisites)

Comment: seems you have another process running of port 7000. what other WSO2 products have are running on the same server? you can check for that process by giving "netstat -nap | grep 7000" (assuming you are on unix/linux OS)

Comment: as a workaround you can do the following. 1. goto $(CARBON_HOME)repository/conf/carbon.xml 2. Change the offset value from 0 to 10 eg: <offset>10</offset> 3. start the BAM server. tell me how it goes

Comment: try following the samples [BAM Samples](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM230/Samples) if any issue let me know

Comment: check the credentials and connection URL for the second issue i'm not sure of the first so i will check and let you know

Comment: it seems this is something to do with postgresql, i haven't worked with BAM + postgresql so i cant say for sure what this is. sorry. you might have to do some digging

Comment: @jacksphere Did you add the driver to BAM? that might be the cause for the connection issue. If you can check the [Documentation](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM230/Samples). you will not have to change much. after you get the PostgreSQL working with BAM you might have to update the hive scripts with the connection details and run the samples.

Comment: one more thing! when adding the datasource PostgreSQL you need to add it to $(CARBON_HOME)/repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml. here is a sample (seems sample too long)

Comment: check here for the configurations [link](https://gist.github.com/nu1silva/250905cf4c814e07845f). hope this helps

Comment: just now i checked as per the Sinthuja response same as ur response..  ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.core.DataSourceRepository} - Error establishing data source connection: org.postgresql.Driver org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.common.DataSourceException: Error establishing data source connection: org.postgresql.Driver when i am clicking on test connection it is not showing healty,so i am facing the above error

Comment: This seems a plain can not connect to db. can you show me the master-datasource.xml configuration? what jar did you include to BAM?

Comment: <datasource>
 <name>Production</name>
<description>The datasource used for analyzer data</description>
 <definition type="RDBMS">
 <configuration>      <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Production</url>
<username>sampletestdba</username>
 <password>sampletest11</password>
               <driverClassName>org.postgresql.Driver</driverClassName>
   <maxActive>50</maxActive>
   <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
  <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
   <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
   <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
    </configuration>

Comment: postgresql_9.0_801.jdbc4_1.0.0.jar file i added in bam,but it seems to be plain but y i dnt know y it is not showing as healthy connection.....

Comment: driver should be ok. configurations should be ok, can you shoe me some more of the log? where did you put the jar? and check for the process "ps -ef | grep java" and check if the jar is on the classpath.

Comment: /home/Downloads/jacksphere/LatestVersion/wso2bam-2.3.0/repository/components/lib

Comment: iam facing below error...ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.reporting.template.core.client.DatasourceClient} -  org.postgresql.Driver
java.sql.SQLException: org.postgresql.Driver

Comment: can you show me the stacktrace? and can you try adding the jar to /home/Downloads/jacksphere/LatestVersion/wso2bam-2.3.0/repository/components/plugins?

Comment: same to same there is no change in error so can u  please tell me what error is this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded the zip file then you can simply extract it and start the server by moving to bin directory and executing the command ./wso2server.sh (in Linux) or wso2server.bat (in Windows).

You also need to install JDK 1.6 or 1.7. **Apache Ant** and **Curl** will also be required to run samples.

If you are working with Windows you need to install Cygwin.

You can further refer to the BAM documents in [1] about installing the product.

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM230/Installing+the+Product

Comment: i am running in linux machine,i added only one postgres jar file in bam.

Comment: ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.core.DataSourceRepository} -  Error establishing data source connection: org.postgresql.Driver
org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.common.DataSourceException: Error establishing data source connection: org.postgresql.Driver

Comment: i added poatgres jar file in lib also.test connection is not showing healty.